# Администраторские права

Tags: c#, wcf

Подскажите можно ли как то сделать чтобы приложение WCF не требовало администраторских прав для запуска? Конкретно вот сервер у меня, соединение по TCP, но если не прожать запуск от админа оно пишет что то про нехватку прав и отваливается. А мне запускать его надо будет на универских компах (по локальной сети), где мне отказываются выдать админские права, говорят у них у самих их нет.

Comment: Может номер порта неправильный? Менее 1024 можно использовать только админу.

Comment: @Sergey нет, я думаю что это скорее всего из-за Mex-Http.

Comment: Не помню что такое этот мех, но помню что в netsh приходилось что-то прописывать.

Comment: @Sergey mex - это штука которая транслирует данные сервиса. Ну т.е. фактически его исходный код или точнее только прототипы... Во всяком случае как я сам понял. Это надо для того чтобы на клиенте автоматически сгенерировался код для прокси. А так как этот mex передает по HTTP, мне кажется это из за него и требуются админ-права. TCP то не должен их требовать по идее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена удалением из конфига всего что связано с Mex.

Comment: Так это не дополнение. Это решение.

Answer (score 1):

Установите для биндинга настройку portSharingEnabled в значение false:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding portSharingEnabled="false" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

После этого WCF вернется к старой модели "одно приложение на порт", в которой назначать права на порты не требуется.

Comment: Нет, что то не помогло.

Comment: Хм, тогда дело в чем-то другом...

Comment: Не может быть в Mex проблема?

Comment: Ну так проверьте.

Comment: Рили!!! В mex-е было дело! Его убрал, перестало требовать админку.

Comment: @DarkByte: Тогда напишите ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Раз сервис требует права, судя по всему, вы используете дуплексное соединение. Значит, вы должны разрешить открытие порта вашему пользователю.

Это делается из-под админской командной строки:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:1234/YourServiceURI user=YOURDOMAIN\youruser
```

Замените `1234` на реальный номер порта, `YourServiceURI` на имя вашего сервиса.

---

Чтение по теме:

- Майкрософтовская документация: [WCF Feature details/Transports/Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- То же программным путём: [WCF selfhosted service, installer class and netsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2522481/276994)

Comment: я же сказал что у меня нет доступа к админским правам на запускаемом компьютере.

Comment: @DarkByte: Без админских прав на инсталляцию — никак. Попросите админа открыть вам этот порт, пусть сам запустит скрипт.

Comment: но почему когда я писал просто через winsock обычными сокетами мне не требовались никакие админ-права, а тут требуются???

Comment: @DarkByte: Потому что вы, судя по всему, используете дуплексное соединение.

Comment: @VladD а что это? :D Вроде не использую.

Comment: @DarkByte: Ну, у вас есть `CallbackContract` в `[ServiceContract]`?

Comment: Да, а что? (15 символов)

Comment: @DarkByte: Тогда скорее всего вам таки понадобится то, что написано в моём ответе :-)

Comment: как я уже ниже отписался вся проблема была в mex-е.

Comment: @DarkByte: Если у вас реально используется CallbackContract, для него нужен доступный порт. А для этого реально понадобится его открыть.